# Algorithm for generating PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE parameter to assign in the script in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

While load testing the login module in jmeter, using  `X-Amz-Target AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.RespondToAuthChallenge`, how is the value for `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE` parameter assigned in the script.

- What is the algorithm for generating that?
- How to use *amplify-js* library for generating the value for `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE` in jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended scripting option for JMeter is [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) therefore I would rather recommend using [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) from the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) rather than trying to use `amplify-js` (whatever it is)

You can check [aws-cognito-java-desktop-app](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-java-desktop-app) for example code.